# Custom reference type

Tags: c++, api, memory-management, architecture, wrapper

I am writing a wrapper around a C-API.

(i) Let `capi_array_data capi_get_array(void)` be a function contained within this library returning a struct containing metadata about a heap-allocated array managed by said API. It would look something like `struct capi_get_array { size_t length; int* arr };` (using `int` for simplicity)

(ii) Such an array can be created by the user manually with `malloc`, `new`, `std::vector`, etc. It must then be registered with `void capi_register_array(int*)`.

I want to make a wrapper class, call it `MyArrayWrapper`, managing such an array with the anatomy of an STL container, supporting `operator[]`, `begin`, `back`, etc. In (i) this wrapper would not own the data, but in (ii) it would. My question now is, whether I should

(a) have one single class that can be constructed using either a `std::initializer_list` (or variadic template for that matter) or an `int*` returned by the API;

(b) have separate classes named something like `MyArrayWrapperRef` and `MyArrayWrapper`, the first handling (i) and the second handling (ii);

(c) optimally have the syntax `MyArrayWrapper&` for (i) and `MyArrayWrapper` for (ii); can this be done?

With (a) there could come up confusion, as one class does two things, which breaks the single-responsibility principle. Answers to questions like "does the copy constructor conduct a deep of shallow copy?" will not be obvious and would require further documentation.

(b) seems like a good choice, but now there are multiple cases: `MyArrayWrapper`, `MyArrayWrapper&`, `MyArrayWrapperRef`, `MyArrayWrapperRef&`. How would they differ? What about `const` references? This might even require another class `MyArrayWrapperConstRef` and again leads to confusion.

(c) is optimal and seems natural with other classes, but I don't know of a way to make it work. I could make a wrapper around `capi_get_array` returning a `MyArrayWrapperRef`, but I would have to save the source of the reference somewhere, right?

Comment: Do you have to call a cleanup function is you call `capi_get_array` without setting your own?

Comment: I've voting to close this as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @NathanOliver The API does do garbage collection automatically on arrays I did not allocate myself.

Comment: do you really need both (i) and (ii) ? How do you know the size of the array returned by `capi_get_array`? Imho some code could clarify a lot

Comment: @user463035818 I edited the question to answer your concern

Comment: Sounds like you could just have one type and use `shard_ptr` with custom deleters to handle all of the cases. Edit : On the other hand, if you have to write several wrapper types, it's not that bad. All of the standard algorithms are generic, and operations on containers should use generic ranges anyway. You just lose out a bit on maintainability, due to repeating code. Edit 2 : You should think carefully about what copy assignment and copy construction means for your wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With (a) there could come up confusion, as one class does two things,
>   which breaks the single-responsibility principle.

You can also see it the other way around: The single responsibility of the wrapper **is** to hide the real ownership and who cleans up what.

Lets say you have this:

```
struct arr_data {
    int* a;
    unsigned size;
};
arr_data get_arr(){
    arr_data ret;
    ret.size = 5;
    ret.a = new int[ret.size];
    return ret;
}
void reg_arr(arr_data x){
    static arr_data store = x;
}
```

Then a simple wrapper could look like this:

```
struct wrapper {
    std::shared_ptr<arr_data> data;
    // implement container-like interface
};

wrapper make_non_owning_wrapper() { 
    auto res = new arr_data();
    *res = get_arr();
    return { std::shared_ptr<arr_data>(res,[](arr_data* x){
            std::cout << "delete x only\n";
            delete x;
    }) };
}

wrapper make_owning_wrapper() {
    auto res = new arr_data();
    res->size = 5;
    res->a = new int[res->size];
    return { std::shared_ptr<arr_data>(res,[](arr_data* x){
        std::cout << "delete both\n";
        delete[] x->a;
        delete x;
    })};
}

int main(){
    auto v = make_owning_wrapper();
    auto w = make_non_owning_wrapper();
    auto z = v;
}
```

Using a shared pointer you can choose a) what to do on clean up and b) what happens when copying a `wrapper` without causing great confusion ;).

Comment: Let me think through this; I actually discarded (a) right off the bat but it does seem reasonable